# once the IM_ServiceRequest table is updated the same changes should be inserted into IM_ServiceRequest _Hx table

Tags: sql-server

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[INSERT_IM_ServiceRequest_Hx] 
ON [dbo].[IM_ServiceRequest] AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO  IM_ServiceRequest_Hx
      SELECT * 
      FROM IM_ServiceRequest

    PRINT 'AFTER INSERT Trigger fired.'
END
```

Comment: Right now, what you're doing is inserting **all rows** from `IM_ServiceRequest` into `IM_ServiceRequest_Hx` any time any new row is added to `IM_ServiceRequest`. You're **NOT** looking at the **newly inserted** rows - you're inserting **ALL ROWS** over and over and over again ..... Also: your title says **updated** but this is an `AFTER INSERT` (not an `AFTER UPDATE`) trigger .....

Comment: when i insert new row  into IM_ServiceRequest only that row should insert into IM_ServiceRequest_Hx table  and if i do any changes in IM_ServiceRequest table for perticular id  that perticular id  changes should insert as a new row into IM_ServiceRequest_Hx

Answer (score 2):

Your current trigger inserts **all rows** into the second table - everytime an `INSERT` happens. Change this by looking at the `Inserted` pseudo table in your trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[INSERT_IM_ServiceRequest_Hx] 
ON [dbo].[IM_ServiceRequest] AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO IM_ServiceRequest_Hx(col1, col2, ...., colN)
      SELECT col1, col2, ..., colN 
      FROM Inserted

    PRINT 'AFTER INSERT trigger fired.'
END
```

**Update:**

the same basically also works for `AFTER UPDATE` triggers, since in that case, the *new* values for the rows modified are also stored in `Inserted`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[UPDATE_IM_ServiceRequest_Hx] 
ON [dbo].[IM_ServiceRequest] AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO IM_ServiceRequest_Hx(col1, col2, ...., colN)
      SELECT col1, col2, ..., colN 
      FROM Inserted

    PRINT 'AFTER UPDATE trigger fired.'
END
```

I would also recommend to always **explicitly** define the column you want to use in your `INSERT INTO ....` statement, and use that same list of columns instead of `SELECT *` when selecting from the `Inserted` pseudo table

Comment: how to insert a perticular row into IM_ServiceRequest_Hx when i update a perticular row in IM_ServiceRequest table